# In R how to control the spacing of points in a line and points plot

Tags: r, plot, line

So I have a `plot()` in R with `type = "o"` so that I can have both line and points. But I find that there are far too many points in the more constant parts of the plot. So, is there a way for me to increase the spacing between each individual points in this plot.

Comment: Hello,  You might get a better answer if you include a reproducible example (read http://www.r-bloggers.com/three-tips-for-posting-good-questions-to-r-help-and-stack-overflow/ which has great advice on posting self contained, simple code examples. )

Answer (score 4):

I would plot the lines using type='l', then go back and use the points function to add just the points that you want.

Comment: ok so the data to plot() is in a datafram df, which I plot with plot(df) and get a line plot (simple example). how would I plot the points and make sure they fall in the same line?

Comment: @sfactor - see `points()` to add your favorite points to the plot. If you haven't invested much time in learning a plotting package, I recommend @Paul's comment into learning ggplot2.

Comment: If you want your plot to look different from the default, then you need to learn the tools and not just the default.  There is a special default for data frames, but you will want to learn to use the plotting functions directly on vectors rather than rely on the data frame method.  You can do this using plot and points (using vectors) but will need to learn the filtering yourself on the points to plot.  Or look into other plotting tools (I second the suggestion of learning ggplot2).

Answer (score 3):

I would recomend you look at the [ggplot2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/) package for drawing graphs in R.  This has several options for dealing with an over abundance of points, my favorite is including an alpha value so the reader can see the difference between one point and ten overlaid.

```
library(ggplot2)
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) + geom_point(alpha = 1/10)
print(d)
```

Comment: It should be print(d) instead of print(p).

Comment: D'Oh !  That's what you get for writing code and not running it first.  Thank you both for the correction...

Answer (score 0):

Please see `help(par)` and the discussion of line types.

*Edit:*  Or just try the following:

```
plot(1:10, type='n', xlim=c(1,10), ylim=c(0,7))
for (i in 1:6) lines(1:10, rep(i, 10), lty=i)
```

which plots six lines with the six pre-defined line types.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the advice proposed by PaulHurleyuk but using the Bioconductor [geneplotter](http://bioconductor.org/help/bioc-views/release/bioc/html/geneplotter.html) package:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("geneplotter")    
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
library(geneplotter)
smoothScatter(diamonds$carat,diamonds$price)
```

[image]